# How can I use the half-qwerty keyboard layout in OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard, software

I'd like to use the [half-qwerty](http://half-qwerty.com/) keyboard layout on my mac, without actually buying any (ridiculously priced) hardware. I found [a auto-hotkey script](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic1326.html), but that appears to be windows-only. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I've listed some alternatives I've found (but aren't quite "it") as answers below.

Comment: You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to create a custom keyboard layout, and use e.g. `Option` as the "flip" key instead of space.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of the one-handed typing Mac apps below. Should be just what you're looking for.

- [One-Hand Keyboard](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/one-hand-keyboard/id465275525?mt=12)
- [One-Hand Keyboard: FREE demo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/one-hand-keyboard-practice/id501185004?mt=12)
- [Mirror-QWERTY](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mirror-qwerty/id496021762?mt=12)

One-Hand Keyboard is the best option, as it has predictive text. Just type the one-hand keys and it will automatically figure out which word you meant. Type `"tges"` and it will change it to `"this"`. Your muscle memory makes it very easy to do this.

Mirror-QWERTY is the non-predictive-text version. You hold spacebar to "mirror" the keys. So to type `"this"` you type `[T] [G+Space] [E+Space] [S]`. I find this a lot harder to do.

I hope one of these solutions works for you! Would love to hear your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I found [One Hand Keyboard](http://www.onehandkeyboard.org/), but at [€79,99](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/one-hand-keyboard/id465275525?mt=12), it's a little too expensive to try out.

Edit: There's now a free demo available on the Mac App Store:

[One-Hand Keyboard [Practice Version]](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/one-hand-keyboard-practice/id501185004?mt=12)

Answer (score 0):

The [Magic Frogpad](http://www.frogpad.com/magic-frogpad.php) also looks promising, but isn't quite half-qwerty, and still forces me to buy expensive hardware (even though I already have the touchpad).